# How to optimize element bindings in an AJAX powered app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, binding

I have an app running mostly on Ajax. Whenever I update content I run a page specific `binder` to initiate/re-initiate functionalities for elements that may have been replaced.

Currently I'm doing this like so:

```
 // pagebinder
 var bindResults = function( page ){
    // element
    var swipesOnPage = page.find('.photoswipeable');

    if ( swipesOnPage.length > 0 && swipesOnPage.jqmData('bound') != true) {
        swipesOnPage
            .jqmData('bound', true )
            .on('click', '.singleLoader', function(e){
                // do somethinbg
            })
            .on('click', '.selector', function(e){
                // do something else
            });
       }
    }
```

So I'm checking if an element is on the page (may have been removed/added) and if an element is found and is not `jqmData(bound)`, I'm setting bindings.

This works ok. but I'm wondering if this is the best way to do this, so

**Question:**
How to best manage element bindings for multiple elements when using an Ajax powered application?

Comment: Do you have a common parent element which will not get changed?

Comment: @Yoshi: since it's running on Jquery Mobile HTML and BODY would be available and persistent throughout the application.

Comment: Seeing that you're allready using the selector-parameter for `on`, why not move the whole thing up to the level of body then. This way you should not have to rebind anything (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: so all my bindings would go to the body tag? I guess I will try that although this will mean more DOM crawling won't it?

Comment: Yes probably, though I'd give it a try. It realy depends of how deeply nested the dom will be.

Comment: ok. Want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you're allready using the *selector-parameter* for [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), why not move the whole thing up to the level of `body` then. This way you should not have to rebind anything.

This will probably result in more dom-traversal, but if the structure isn't too deeply nested, it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: I played around with it, but since I'm carrying around a big DOM, for the moment I'm staying with my above binding. Need to fiddle some more. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), though it would probably get too messy for larger apps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but there would be a lot to delegate and I'm more troubled by making sure I'm not rebinding to elements when re-running `bindResults()` after an Ajax update